# Libtorrent: how can I get all torrent handles associated with a session?

Tags: python, libtorrent, libtorrent-rasterbar

If I have added multiple torrents in a session, is there any way I can get all the handles from that session ?

For eg.

```
h1 = ses.add_torrent(params)
h2 = ses.add_torrent(params)
h3 = ses.add_torrent(params)
```

is session has any method which can give me the list of all the handles associated with that session.
like.

```
li=sess.get_all_handles()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a function on the session object called [get_torrents()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#get_torrents()) which returns a vector of all torrent_handles.